# Did the FAA order the installation of "Cooper vanes?"

Tags: faa-regulations, aviation-history, modifications, hijack, boeing-727

On November 24, 1971, a man [hijacked a Boeing 727](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D._B._Cooper) and parachuted away, never to be found.

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cooper_vane), this prompted (together with 2 other hijackings) the installation of "Cooper vanes" devices that prevented the opening of the 727 ventral airstair in flight.

> In the United States, following three hijackings in 1972, the Federal Aviation Administration ordered that Boeing 727 aircraft be fitted with Cooper vanes.

Wikipedia cites "Beyond Fear: Thinking Sensibly About Security in an Uncertain World," which I don't have access to. I can find the same claim [here](https://www.airliners.net/forum/viewtopic.php?t=368849) and [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/aviation/comments/4w6mwh/would_there_be_a_way_to_exit_a_passenger_jet_at/).

I couldn't find any [Federal Aviation Regulations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Federal_Aviation_Regulations) specifically mentioning "727." I also couldn't find any [Airworthiness Directives](https://www.faa.gov/regulations_policies/airworthiness_directives/search/?q=727&makeModel=&type=Current&filter=&sort=effectiveDate&direction=asc&startRow=26) specifically mentioning "727" relevant to the situation. There is [this one](http://rgl.faa.gov/Regulatory_and_Guidance_Library/rgAD.nsf/AOCADSearch/3F7C4A93F8EEEFE486256832004AA147?OpenDocument). Furthermore, the policy change isn't mentioned [here](http://aireform.com/resources/faa-history-pages/faa-history-1972/).

1. Did the FAA order the installation of "Cooper vanes" on Boeing 727 aircraft?
2. Was the "order" in 1972?

I am asking this question because of a recent April 2 answer on [Aviation.SE](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/61924/1467):

> Boeing did have a small regional jet called the Boeing 727. This plane was designed to operate at smaller airports, with independence from ground facilities as a selling feature. The best example is that the 727 had built-in stairs in the rear underbelly of the aircraft. **This could be opened in flight until some hijacker known as DB Cooper jumped out to make his escape.**

Apologies if the background research is poorly conducted and irrelevant. I am not familiar with the best way to research historic and current FAA "orders."

Comment: This question has been asked on [Skeptics.SE](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/43769/did-the-faa-order-the-installation-of-cooper-vanes) and wasn't well received.

Comment: Don't think anybody (source of bottom quote) who characterizes the 727 as a "small regional jet" has much credibility, or much clue.

Comment: FWIW, *Beyond Fear* (I have a copy) provides no citation for that claim.

Comment: @StephenS Thank you for your comment. This clears up a potential avenue of time-wasting.

Comment: @RalphJ The quote came from a question titled "Why didn't Boeing produce its own regional jet?" (cited in the question above). All answers (and all upvoted) included the Boeing 727 in the list of Boeing regional jets. If you disagree with this classification, you should post a separate (and better) answer.

Comment: As said in Skeptics about hijack->vane " The model of choice was the Boeing 727 — introduced in 1964 — because its rear air stairway was easier to open and exit during flight.
“There was a little fin on the back of the airplane,” said Crooks, who compared the 727’s rear stairway to the exit in a C-130. “When it got into the air stream there was a latch over this fin that held the door up. You could engage the hydraulic system and push it right through that fin. The fin would break right off.”" (from https://aviaed.wordpress.com/2011/11/23/d-b-cooper-case-inspired-copycat-hijackings-in-reno/)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The answer to both of your questions is "yes". The FAA ordered, in effect, the installation of "Cooper Vanes" and did do so in 1972.

The reason you could not find the answer may have been that the modifications were not called "Cooper Vanes" by the FAA and nor was the FAA targeting the 727 specifically. Instead they addressed ventral and tailcone exits on any aircraft.

[CFR 14, Part 25 (Airworthiness Standards: Transport Category Airplanes), Subpart D (Design and Construction, Emergency Provisions)](http://rgl.faa.gov/Regulatory_and_Guidance_Library/rgFAR.nsf/0/42B6073445F438F28525667200519C29?OpenDocument) contains, since 31st of December 1972, the following text (emphasis mine):

> Sec. 25.809
>
> Emergency exit arrangement.
>
> ...
>
> (j) When required by the operating rules for any large passenger-carrying turbojet powered airplane, each **ventral exit and tailcone exit** must be--
>
> (1) **Designed and constructed so that it cannot be opened during flight**; and
>
> (2) Marked with a placard readable from a distance of 30 inches and installed at a conspicuous location near the means of opening the exit, stating that the exit has been designed and constructed so that it cannot be opened during flight

This rule was announced in the [Notice of Proposed Rulemaking. Notice No. 72-15](http://rgl.faa.gov/Regulatory_and_Guidance_Library/rgNPRM.nsf/2ed8a85bb3dd48e68525644900598dfb/666840bc661701298525692300644ab4!OpenDocument), Issued on June 6th, 1972.

It clearly references the hijackings as the reason for this change.

> ....
>
> In spite of concerted efforts made by the FAA and the air carriers,
>   incidents continue to occur wherein the safety of the flight of
>   aircraft engaged in passenger-carrying operations under Part 121 of
>   the Federal Aviation Regulations has been jeopardized by persons
>   intending to harm the crew or take command of the airplane. **On a
>   number of occasions in recent hijackings, the ventral exit of an
>   airplane has been opened and a hijacker aboard has parachuted from the
>   airplane through that exit**. The agency recognizes that every possible
>   step must be taken to deter persons from boarding aircraft for such a
>   hijacking purpose. Accordingly, the FAA deems it appropriate to
>   propose certain amendments to Parts 25 and 121.
>
> Specifically, it is proposed to amend Sec 25.809 to provide that, when
>   required by the operating rules, for any large passenger carrying
>   turbojet powered air-plane an approved means must be provided so that:
>
> (1) takeoff cannot be started if either the ventral exit or tail cone
>   exit is not locked; and
>
> (2) neither the ventral exit nor the tail cone
>   exit can be opened in flight.
>
> A similar amendment is proposed to be made to Sec 121.310, to become
>   effective with respect to persons conducting operations under Part 121
>   six months following its adoption.
>
> However, it is to be noted that to achieve compliance with the
>   proposed regulation both the ventral exit and tail cone exit would
>   have to continue to meet all of the requirements applicable to their
>   approval as emergency exits. Specifically, to achieve compliance, the
>   conditions that would have to be met to obtain approval of
>   modification to the locking mechanisms of these two exits are as
>   follows:
>
> (1) The mechanism must be locked while the airplane is
>   aloft;
>
> (2) Takeoff of the airplane cannot be started if either ventral
>   or tail cone is not locked; and
>
> (3) The exit must be available for use
>   in the event of an emergency.

Since Part 25 is for airworthiness certification of new aircraft, an additional change was proposed to Part 121 so that operator of existing aircraft were given 6 months to apply the new rules to already certified aircraft.

Somehow the change to Sec 121.310 cannot be found in the [FAA Regulatory and Guidance Library](http://rgl.faa.gov/Regulatory_and_Guidance_Library/rgFAR.nsf/MainFrame?OpenFrameset) (at least not dated 1972), even though the [final rule](http://rgl.faa.gov/Regulatory_and_Guidance_Library/rgFinalRule.nsf/a09133bddc7f4fbb8525646000609712/7b9e871dbcb13669862568d4006cd48f!OpenDocument) of 30th November 1972  includes it.

A [revision of 121.310 from 1997](http://rgl.faa.gov/Regulatory_and_Guidance_Library/rgFAR.nsf/0/502EB01FBD96A950852566EF006B946A?OpenDocument) includes the text.

---

Special thanks to the FAA for making the pre-internet era rulemaking archives easily accessible through the internet.

Comment: I have accepted this answer. Could I ask how you went about finding it (e.g. tips)? This would be really helpful in the future.

Comment: Hello Barry, welcome to Aviation.stackexchange.com. Finding the rules and notices of rulemaking was harder than I thought. Experience with aviation regulations helped a lot. I knew that in regulations, rarely a solution (e.g. Cooper vane or more technical term) is mandated, but instead the desired effect is mandated. I also knew that to address already existing type certified aircraft, the FAA would have to address both the certification rule (e.g. Part 25) and the operational rules (e.g. Part 121). I also suspected that the problem would be address generically, not only on the Boeing 727.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply! You mentioned 2 very interesting points.  I suppose what you mean is experience helped you find the regulations?

Comment: I started my search in the [FAA RGL](https://rgl.faa.gov/Regulatory_and_Guidance_Library/rgFAR.nsf/MainFrame?OpenFrameset) on the history of part 121, as that would be the obvious choice to address existing airline operations. I couldn't find any relevant changes in 1972. In found relevant text in Part 125, Appendix A.1 (existing since 1978, so too new). Using words from that text, I found the relevant amendment to Section 25.809, which in turn linked to the proposed rulemaking and the final note.

Comment: Ah, thank you so much! I don't think I would've been able to do this, even after hours of searching.

Comment: You're welcome. As I said, experience with these kind of regulations / being an aviation nerd helped a lot :-)